# Before calling `reduxifyNavigator`, please call `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware`, so that we know when to trigger your listener

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const { store, persistor } = configureStores();

const navMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  'root,
  state => state.nav,
 );
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      state: state.nav,
  });
const listener = reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigator, 'root');
```

I followed the above sequence order but still, the error isn't getting resolved.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSO6H.png)